# Unable to install R package because of fortran

Tags: r, compiler-errors, gfortran

I am trying to install this package in R

```
install.packages('rmutil')

gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-tbZjLv/r-base-4.1.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c cutil.c -o cutil.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-tbZjLv/r-base-4.1.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c dist.c -o dist.o
77 -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-tbZjLv/r-base-4.1.0=. -fstack-protector-strong  -c gettvc.f -o gettvc.o
/bin/bash: 77: command not found
make: *** [/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:191: gettvc.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rmutil’
* removing ‘/home/alessandro/R_libs/rmutil’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rmutil’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpOZ5A2U/downloaded_packages’
```

What I don't understand is that I do have gfortran installed on my ubuntu.

Any help is welcome

Comment: Looks like the package has been installed in the directory ```
‘/tmp/RtmpOZ5A2U/downloaded_packages’ ``` So I am not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Do `sudo apt install r-base-dev` because that package will bring what is needed to compile many/most packages from sources -- including the Fortran compiler and development package.

Comment: Also, I just checked and `rmutil` installs fine for me on Ubuntu (20.10, using the standard R package via the CRAN mirror for Ubuntu) but calls `gfortran`.  The "77" in you command log may be indicative of an issue at your end.  Did you install R from source or from binary?

Comment: I installed R from source. and if I try to reinstall it aptitude tells me there is nothing to do

Comment: If you insalled from source you _must have had sufficient Fortran compiling abilities_ when you did. But something is _wrong_ and non-standard as evidenced by the echoed '77' in what you quoted.  Based on the limited information given, I cannot help you anymore besides recommending that if in doubt, use the binary package. I do so myself.

Comment: I agree with you, it definitely should be working. I installed from source, I have Fortran, GFortran, etc ... I agree with your binary package solution, it just drives me crazy because I have an error that should not exist.

Comment: What I also tried to say, but that was maybe too far between the lines, was that using the (binary) package(s) from the CRAN repos for Ubuntu (see [the README](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu)) will "just work".  By package I mean `r-base-core` along with `r-base-dev` ensuring build dependencies.

Comment: Ahh ok, sorry indeed I misunderstood. I am gonna try this.

Comment: I did but still getting the error 77: command not found. However, I can guarantee I have fortran and gfortran installed. I do not understand what else I could do.

Comment: gortran AND fort77 are both installed

Answer (score 1):

Ok it seemed I had 2 versions of R installed

```
/usr/bin/R
/usr/R
```

I got rid of the two and reinstalled R properly.

I also had to delete this

```
rm ~/.R/Makevars
```

this file was giving R wrong instructions about the location of gfortran. I just deleted it.

Comment: Same problem here, how did you uninstall both? is there a way to keep one but just remove the other?